# View is slow when loading using AdMob

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

This is my `onCreate` in my `activity.java` class:

```
private Button jhaButton;
SegmentedGroup mySegControl;
private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712"; //Test ads
private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_jha);


    // Initialize the Mobile Ads SDK.
    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {}
    });

    // Create the InterstitialAd and set the adUnitId.
    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    // Defined in res/values/strings.xml
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            Toast.makeText(JHAActivity.this, "onAdLoaded()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            Toast.makeText(JHAActivity.this,
                    "onAdFailedToLoad() with error code: " + errorCode,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Load the next interstitial.
            interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
    });

    jhaButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    jhaButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openJHA();
        }
    });
}
```

When I run my app, and open this `activity.java` view, it almost takes 2 seconds before the view device actually perform this action. Any tips?

Comment: "Slow" is a relative term. Maybe your internet connection is slow, your phone is not good or any other server related problem could be to blame here. Your code looks ok to me, so probably your ad id hasn't loaded that many ads yet.

Comment: @GauravMall I am running this on a simulator, because I do not have an Android phone myself. May that be the reason?

Comment: Could be. I suggest that you try this with a `testId` if it loads ok, then it's your ids problem (meaning you need to wait for ads to be fetched). If it loads slowly, then probably it is the simulators problem. Your code is good, no need to worry :)

Comment: @GauravMall Good to know :) Just a question. This code is in my second activity controller(this activity view is shown after a button press). Should I move a part of the code to the first/main activity controller?

Comment: No need to move the code. If I'm right you're showing the ad when a button is clicked. So, the ad has time to load. You're good to continue development :)